# Does CKAN have a limit size of data to upload?

Tags: solr, ckan

I have set CKAN and it is running fine, but have two questions.
Both problems below happen only if uploading `file`. If I add a new resource by a URL, everything runs fine.

1) I can upload small files (around 4kb) to a given dataset, but when trying with bigger files (65 kb) I get `Error 500 An Internal Server Error Occurred`. So is there a size limit for uploading files? What can I do to be able to upload bigger files?

2) I get another error, for the small uploaded files, and that is: when clicking in `Go to Resource` to download the data, it gives me `Connection to localhost refused`, and I cant visualize the data either. What am I doing wrong?

I appreciate any help. If you need me to provide more info on anything, I'll happily do.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CKAN has an upload size limit of 10MB for resources by default. You can raise that in your ini with ckan.max_resource_size = XX, for example ckan.max_resource_size = 100 (which means = 100MB).

As for question 2): have you set `ckan.site_url` correctly in your ini?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, CKAN can easily cope with terabytes of data(Used for millions of medical records in hospitals etc) so there shouldn't be an issue with your file size. It could be an issue on their end while receiving your data.

Comment: Could it be Jetty limiting the size of the files? Do you know how I check if Jetty is the problem here? Thank you!

Comment: You would be correct; http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/configuring-form-size.html